# Why does this GradientDescentOptimizer get stuck?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm trying to write an example of using a `GradientDescentOptimizer`, but the optimization gets stuck pretty quickly.  All of my data is generated according to the formula `y = (2 * x_1) + (8 * x_2)`, so shouldn't it be pretty easy for gradient descent to find an optimal solution, since there are no local minima?

```
import numpy as np 
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf 

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

np.random.seed(101) 
tf.set_random_seed(101) 

n_values = 100
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 1000

x_vals = np.random.random_sample((n_values, 2))
y_vals = [(2 * x_vals[i][0] + 8 * x_vals[i][1]) for i in range(n_values)]
y_vals = np.reshape(y_vals, (-1, 1))

n_dims = x_vals.shape[1]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2]) 
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 

W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1, n_dims])) 

y_pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X, W), axis=(-1, 1))  
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred - Y, 2)) / (2 * tf.cast(n_values, tf.float32))  
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost) 

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess: 

    sess.run(init) 

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):           
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X : x_vals, Y : y_vals})           
        if (epoch) % 50 == 0: 
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {X : x_vals, Y : y_vals}) 
            print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W))
```

Here are the results

```
Epoch 1 : cost = 1048.1746 W = [[1.2004547 1.21069  ]] 
Epoch 51 : cost = 429.50342 W = [[4.111497 4.421291]]
Epoch 101 : cost = 428.04016 W = [[4.170494  4.6341734]]
Epoch 151 : cost = 427.94107 W = [[4.1271544 4.6886673]] 
Epoch 201 : cost = 427.90067 W = [[4.0954566 4.720226 ]] 
Epoch 251 : cost = 427.88373 W = [[4.0747733 4.740489 ]] 
Epoch 301 : cost = 427.87656 W = [[4.0613766 4.7535996]]
Epoch 351 : cost = 427.8736 W = [[4.0527034 4.762087 ]]
Epoch 401 : cost = 427.8724 W = [[4.0470877 4.767582 ]] 
Epoch 451 : cost = 427.87186 W = [[4.043453  4.7711387]] 
Epoch 501 : cost = 427.87167 W = [[4.0411    4.7734404]] 
Epoch 551 : cost = 427.87155 W = [[4.039577  4.7749314]] 
Epoch 601 : cost = 427.87146 W = [[4.0385904 4.775896 ]] 
Epoch 651 : cost = 427.87152 W = [[4.0379524 4.7765207]]
Epoch 701 : cost = 427.87146 W = [[4.0375395 4.776925 ]]
Epoch 751 : cost = 427.87143 W = [[4.0372725 4.7771864]] 
Epoch 801 : cost = 427.87146 W = [[4.0370994 4.7773557]] 
Epoch 851 : cost = 427.8714 W = [[4.0369873 4.777465 ]]
Epoch 901 : cost = 427.87146 W = [[4.036914  4.7775364]] 
Epoch 951 : cost = 427.87146 W = [[4.036866 4.777584]]
```

The `W` values are still changing a tiny bit, but if I increase the epochs, the `W` values eventually stop changing at all.  I can change the learning rate, but all that does it cause it to get stuck earlier or later.

Why isn't the `GradientDescentOptimizer` able to find a solution for this perfect dataset with no randomness?  Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

**The dimensions of y_pred and Y should be consistent in the code below. But y_pred is one-dimensional, Y is two-dimensional**

```
y_pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X, W), axis=(-1, 1))
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred - Y, 2)) / (2 * tf.cast(n_values, tf.float32))
```

**You can try the code below and it will produce the expected output.**

```
y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X, W),axis=1),shape=(-1,1))
```

Comment: I don't understand.  When you're doing a linear regression, isn't the formula always something like `y = (w_1 * x_1) + (w_2 * x_2) + ... + (w_n * x_n) + b`?  So then wouldn't `Y` always be one-dimensional and `X` is n-dimensional?